# Is there difference between "I recommend he (should) become a florist." and "I recommend him to be a florist."

Tags: difference, translation

1. I recommend he (should) become a florist.
2. I recommend him to be a florist.

I see no difference between them.

Would there be any difference by meaning?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: FWIW, I would suggest that the most idiomatic way to phrase this would be 'I recommend for him to become a florist', or 'I recommend that he become a florist'. In fact, the clearest way of expressing this might be to rephrase altogether to omit the 'recommend', e.g. 'In my opinion, he should become a florist'.

Comment: The first prescribes a course of action. The second sounds like someone has asked you for a reference and you are giving him or her your recommendation. They have very different meanings.